# can i use a 20V, 2.0A for my laptop that needs 19V, 4.74 A?

Tags: charger, output, laptop

i have a laptop that needs 19V and 4.74A
my laptop's charger broke and i replaced it with a 20V and 2.0 A
the laptop seems fine but i noticed that the charging goes on and off for like an interval or 1-2 minutes if i use it heavily. but if i just place it on standby or i dont do too much work (still charging) the charging goes normally and it will now not go on and off the same also when i shut down my laptop and charge it. i know that you must follow the right voltage and ampere for your device but is it alright if i continue to use it? any advice? your answers will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power supply can't provide enough current to both charge the battery and run the computer.  Fortunately your computer seems clever enough to realise this and make a choice - charge the battery, or run the computer.  When you're using the computer and consequently consuming more current the charge circuit gets shut down since it doesn't have enough current available to it.

So what would the consequences be of long term use?  Hard to say really, but two that spring to mind might be:

1. Reduced battery life due to "stop-start" charging (some say it effects the batteries, some say it doesn't).
2. Overheating power supply (you're over-stressing it)

So should you continue to use it?  Well, in the short term, until the power supply melts, there shouldn't be too much to worry about, but you should really look at getting a new properly rated supply before your current one breaks.  It may break in 3 years time, or it may break tomorrow.